# Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from pattern)

Tags: python-3.x, pip

When I try to install the pattern package using "pip install pattern", it tried to install "mysqlclient" but could not match any version for pattern and generate the following errors.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysqlclient (from pattern)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mysqlclient
Would anyone please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your OS and python version?

Comment: Environment: Linux and python: 3.6.9

Comment: do you need to upgrade pip? `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Currently, I am using the latest version of pip.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue: `pip 21.0.1`, `Python 3.6.9`,

Comment: probably we should install more dependencies upfront. check readme: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue and used the following way and it works!

Before pip install mysqlclient run this :

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Comment: Thank you for this. FYI for Mac users, I had to do this because I install MySQL on the mac via the website and `mysql` is not in my path. Also, for what's its worth, ChatGPT 4 led me down the wrong path because I guess it assumes that `mysql` is on the path since most users install via brew.